# Validate Yii2 Activeform on simple button click

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I want to validate my Yii2 activeform on simple button click which is not submitButton. I tried `$('#formId').yiiActiveForm("validate")` but it is not working.

I also tried - `$('#formId').yiiActiveForm('submitForm')` it validates form but it also submit it if everything is ok. I don't want to submit that form. I just want to validate it on button click and if everything is ok than i want to open a modal popup.

What are possible ways to validate this activeform on button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate your form perform ajax validation only inside your action as follows. This will only validate your form

```
public function actionValidateForm() {
        $model = new Form();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::$app->end();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin. Almost done can u suggest one more thing. It is not removing error class from field. even after entring correct data. Validation is working fine just error message is not getting removed

Comment: you need to set form properties like

`enableAjaxValidation,enableClientValidation,validateOnChange,validateOnSubmit` to `true`

Comment: I tried validateOnChange and validateOnBlur but error message is still displaying.

Comment: what about `enableAjaxValidation` ? is it set to true

Comment: it is set to value true

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `enableClientValidation = false,` in you'r form's options .